# pywhatkit opening the same youtube video

Tags: python

When trying to get pywhatkit to open a youtube video, it works, except it opens the same youtube video every time. one that i did not request

```
 if 'play' in command:
        song = command.replace('play', '')
        talk('playing' + song)
        pywhatkit.playonyt('song')
```

It keeps opening this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jq_WDQsKYu8&ab_channel=PopularMusic

Comment: shouldn't be `song` without `' '` in `pywhatkit.playonyt( song )` ? Using `'song'` you send text `"song"` instead of value from variable `song`

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotes around `song`:

```py
pywhatkit.playonyt(song)
```

Comment: Please use full words and format your code.